# Making lxml.objectify ignore xml namespaces?

Tags: python, xml, lxml, xml-namespaces

So I gotta deal with some xml that looks like this:

```
<ns2:foobarResponse xmlns:ns2="http://api.example.com">
  <duration>206</duration>
  <artist>
    <tracks>...</tracks>
  </artist>
</ns2:foobarResponse>
```

I found lxml and it's [objectify](http://codespeak.net/lxml/objectify.html) module, that lets you traverse a xml document in a pythonic way, like a dictionary.
Problem is: it's using the bogus xml namespace every time you try to access an element, like this:

```
from lxml import objectify

tree = objectify.fromstring(xml)
print tree.artist
# ERROR: no such child: {http://api.example.com}artist
```

It's trying to access `<artist>` with the parent namespace, but the tag doesn't use the ns.

Any ideas how to get around this? Thanks

Comment: no. you can trick lxml by [feeding a patched root node start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412496/python-elementtree-module-how-to-ignore-the-namespace-of-xml-files-to-locate-ma/76601149#76601149), but then it throws XMLSyntaxError on `</ns2:foobarResponse>` because `ns2` is undefined. your best bet is to find another XML parser, which returns the "localname" of every node, here: `foobarResponse`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the lxml.objectify [documentation](http://codespeak.net/lxml/objectify.html#namespace-handling), attribute lookups default to using the namespace of their parent element.

What you probably *want* to work would be:

```
print tree["{}artist"]
```

QName syntax like this would work if your children had a non-empty namespace ("{http://foo/}artist", for instance), but unfortunately, it looks like the current source code treats an empty namespace as *no* namespace, so all of objectify's lookup goodness will helpfully replace the empty namespace with the parent namespace, and you're out of luck.

This is either a bug ("{}artist" should work), or an enhancement request to file for the lxml folks.

For the moment, the best thing to do is probably:

```
print tree.xpath("artist")
```

It's unclear to me how much of a performance hit you'll take using xpath here, but this certainly works.

Answer (score 3):

Just for reference: Note that this works as expected since lxml 2.3.

From the lxml changelog:

> "
>   [...]
>
> 2.3 (2011-02-06) Features added
>
> - When looking for children, lxml.objectify takes '{}tag' as meaning 
>     an empty namespace, as opposed to the parent namespace.
>
> [...]"

In action:

```
>>> xml = """<ns2:foobarResponse xmlns:ns2="http://api.example.com">
...   <duration>206</duration>
...   <artist>
...     <tracks>...</tracks>
...   </artist>
... </ns2:foobarResponse>"""
>>> tree = objectify.fromstring(xml)
>>> print tree['{}artist']
artist = None [ObjectifiedElement]
    tracks = '...' [StringElement]
>>>
```