# Suppress namespace in ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

Given an xml file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?>
<Message xmlns="http://example.com/ns" xmlns:myns="urn:us:gov:dot:faa:aim:saa">
  <foo id="stuffid"/>
  <myns:bar/>
</Message>
```

When I parse it with ElementTree, the element tags look like:

```
{http://example.com/ns}Message
  {http://example.com/ns}foo
  {urn:us:gov:dot:faa:aim:saa}bar
```

But I'd rather just have

```
Message
  foo
  bar
```

and more importantly, I'd rather just pass "Message", "foo", and "bar" into the `find()` and `findall()` methods.

I've tried using substitutions to censor all `xmlns:` attributes as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/15641319/338479 (and this is probably what I'll have to do if I can't find something more elegant), and I've tried calling `ElementTree.register_namespace('', "http://example.com/ns")` but that seems to only help with `ElementTree.tostring()`, which isn't what I wanted.

Isn't there just some way to get ElementTree to pretend it never heard of `xmlns`?

Let's assume that my element tags are globally unique even without the namespace qualifiers. In this case, the namespaces just get in the way.

---

Addressing some of the comments in detail:

Joe linked to [Python ElementTree module: How to ignore the namespace of XML files to locate matching element when using the method "find", "findall"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412496/python-elementtree-module-how-to-ignore-the-namespace-of-xml-files-to-locate-ma) which is close enough to my question that I guess mine is a duplicate. However, that question was not answered either. The suggestions given there were:

- Use `tree.findall("xmlns:DEAL_LEVEL/xmlns:PAID_OFF", namespaces={'xmlns': 'http://www.test.com'})`.

  - I couldn't find the documentation for that call with those arguments in https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.findall, and at any rate it requires that I know all of the namespaces.
- Pre-process the input XML and strip the xmlns attributes from the input as mentioned above.
- Post-process the parsed document and strip all the namespaces from the tags.

  - Frankly, I like this approach the best. I will post the code as an answer.
- Use `register_namespace("", "http://example.com/ns")`

  - This suppresses the namespace when using `ElementTree.tostring(el)` but not in `el.tag`. I expect it doesn't help `find()` or `findall()` either.
  - Again, this doesn't solve the problem where I need to know all the namespaces in advance (or extract them from the document somehow).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python ElementTree module: How to ignore the namespace of XML files to locate matching element when using the method "find", "findall"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412496/python-elementtree-module-how-to-ignore-the-namespace-of-xml-files-to-locate-ma)

Comment: Yes its a dup.  Just set the value of  the xmlns attribute to the empty string as shown at the URL in the comment above.

Comment: I've edited my post and addressed these comments. Thanks for the links.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, thanks for the links to the other question. I've decided to borrow (and improve on) [one of the solutions given there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25920989/338479):

```
def stripNs(el):
  '''Recursively search this element tree, removing namespaces.'''
  if el.tag.startswith("{"):
    el.tag = el.tag.split('}', 1)[1]  # strip namespace
  for k in el.attrib.keys():
    if k.startswith("{"):
      k2 = k.split('}', 1)[1]
      el.attrib[k2] = el.attrib[k]
      del el.attrib[k]
  for child in el:
    stripNs(child)
```

Comment: `for k in el.attrib.keys():` should be `keys = list(el.attrib.keys()); for k in keys:` or something similar because you are deleting one of the keys and could get a "dictionary keys changed during iteration" runtime error.