# How to shorten the filter query in lxml

Tags: xml, parsing, xml-parsing, namespaces, lxml

I am parsing an xml that has custom name space using lxml . Excerpt from the xml is given below.

```
<abcd:ABCDCfg xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:abcd="http://www.xyzv.com/abcd">
   <abcd:Section name="Features" display-name="Features" desc=“Parameters”>
     <abcd:Param name=“mode”>
        <abcd:Type>string</abcd:Type>
        <abcd:Persistent>true</abcd:Persistent>
        <abcd:Configurable>true</abcd:Configurable>
        <abcd:ReadAccess>aup</abcd:ReadAccess>
        <abcd:WriteAccess>ap</abcd:WriteAccess>
        <abcd:DisplayName>Mode</abcd:DisplayName>
     </abcd:Param>
   </abcd:Section>
</abcd:ABCDCfg>
```

Right now when I am finding values in the xml I am using like this

```
sections = xmltree.findall('{http://www.xyzv.com/abcd}Section')
if (child.tag =='{http://www.xyzv.com/abcd}Param')
```

Is there anyway in lxml which will enable me to use lxml without the namespace. Something like

```
sections = xmltree.findall('Section')
if (child.tag =='Param')
```

This will make the code really readable. Any help would be welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is applicable in your case, you can just *remove all the namespaces from the tree* after parsing. I'd go with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25920989/771848). Working sample in Python 3:

```
import lxml.etree as ET
from io import BytesIO


data = b"""<abcd:ABCDCfg xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:abcd="http://www.xyzv.com/abcd">
   <abcd:Section name="Features" display-name="Features" desc="Parameters">
     <abcd:Param name="mode">
        <abcd:Type>string</abcd:Type>
        <abcd:Persistent>true</abcd:Persistent>
        <abcd:Configurable>true</abcd:Configurable>
        <abcd:ReadAccess>aup</abcd:ReadAccess>
        <abcd:WriteAccess>ap</abcd:WriteAccess>
        <abcd:DisplayName>Mode</abcd:DisplayName>
     </abcd:Param>
   </abcd:Section>
</abcd:ABCDCfg>"""

it = ET.iterparse(BytesIO(data))
for _, el in it:
    if '}' in el.tag:
        el.tag = el.tag.split('}', 1)[1]  # strip all namespaces
root = it.root

sections = root.findall('Section')
print(sections)
```

Prints:

```
[<Element Section at 0x10636d0c8>]
```

which means we can find elements in the tree without specifying namespaces at all.