# parse a xml file in python which nested tags are there

Tags: python, xml

i just want to parse one xml file which is like as

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Significant Major="3" Minor="0" Revision="1" xmlns="urn:reuterscompanycontent:significantdevelopments03"><RepNo>0091N</RepNo><CompanyName Type="Primary">XYZ</CompanyName><Production Date="2017-02-23T18:10:39" /><Developments><Development ID="3534388"><Dates><Source>2017-02-23T18:18:32</Source><Initiation>2017-02-23T18:18:32</Initiation><LastUpdate>2017-02-23T18:23:26</LastUpdate></Dates><Flags><FrontPage>0</FrontPage><Significance>1</Significance></Flags><Topics><Topic1 Code="254">Regulatory / Company Investigation</Topic1></Topics><Headline>FTC approves final order settling charges for Abbott's deal with St. Jude Medical</Headline></Development></Developments></Significant>
```

I just want to parse the Development tag and parse its every nested tag
i have below code:

```py
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
tree = ET.ElementTree(file='../rawdata/SigDev_0091N.xml')

#get the root element
root = tree.getroot()

#print root.tag, root.attrib

for child in root:
#print child.tag, child.attrib
    name = child.tag
    print name
    print 'at line 13'
    if name is 'Developments':
        print 'at line 15'
        for devChild in name['Developments']:
            print devChild.tag,devChild.attrib
```

it is not going inside the if block, i dont know why?

Comment: Your indentation is messed up here! Is it also in your script file?

Comment: no no not in script file indentation is very much correct

Comment: There is an edit button in the lower left of your post.  Please use it to correct your formatting.  Python *Cares* about formatting....

Comment: @StephenRauch done with indentation.

Comment: See : [Parsing XML with namespace in Python via 'ElementTree'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking `name is 'Developments'` always return `false` as `child.tag` is returning the value in `{xmlns}tagname` format.

For your case:

> name = {urn:reuterscompanycontent:significantdevelopments03}Developments

You may refer to the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412496/python-elementtree-module-how-to-ignore-the-namespace-of-xml-files-to-locate-ma).

Simple string methods `strip()`, `find()`, `split()` or `re` can help you to skip the namespace for comparison.

Python documentation related: https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#parsing-xml-with-namespaces

Comment: can u please help me out while parsing it. suppose i want to get the value of source in development, then how will i?