# Trying to parse XML response in Python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am trying to obtain the value of 2 elements (**Result and AuthenticationKey**)from this XML. The `<s:Envelope>` syntax is throwing me off.

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <AuthenticateResponse xmlns="http://remote.Services">
         <AuthenticateResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/remote.Services.Api.DataContracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <AdditionalInfo i:nil="true"/>
            <ErrorMessage i:nil="true"/>
            <ErrorMessageId i:nil="true"/>
            <ErrorMessages i:nil="true" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
            <InternalId>0</InternalId>
            <RecordsAffected>0</RecordsAffected>
            <Result>true</Result>
            <WarningMessages i:nil="true" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
            <a:AuthenticationKey>SUPERSECRETTOKEN</a:AuthenticationKey>
            <a:UserGrpId>YYY</a:UserGrpId>
            <a:UserId>XXX</a:UserId>
         </AuthenticateResult>
      </AuthenticateResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Here is the relevant line of code that is returning a None. Both lines of code are returning a None.

I tried to use the code from another question on stackoverflow, but I am not sure on how to introduce the namespaces in the find method for this particular xml.

```
tree = ElementTree.fromstring(resp.text)
    token = tree.find("AuthenticateResponse") #Option1
    token = tree.find("Envelope/Body/AuthenticateResponse/AuthenticateResult/AuthenticationKey") #Option2
    print token
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853243/parsing-xml-with-namespace-in-python-via-elementtree

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `xmlns` part becomes a prefix for your `tags`, i.e. to find `AuthenticateResponse` you would need to search for `{http://remote.Services}AuthenticateResponse`.

```
print(list(tree)[0].find('{http://remote.Services}AuthenticateResponse'))
>>> <Element '{http://remote.Services}AuthenticateResponse' at 0x00000000027228B8>
```

For a more general solution have a look at the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25920989/2776376).

```
from io import StringIO
tree = ET.iterparse(StringIO("""<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <AuthenticateResponse xmlns="http://remote.Services">
         <AuthenticateResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/remote.Services.Api.DataContracts" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <AdditionalInfo i:nil="true"/>
            <ErrorMessage i:nil="true"/>
            <ErrorMessageId i:nil="true"/>
            <ErrorMessages i:nil="true" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
            <InternalId>0</InternalId>
            <RecordsAffected>0</RecordsAffected>
            <Result>true</Result>
            <WarningMessages i:nil="true" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"/>
            <a:AuthenticationKey>SUPERSECRETTOKEN</a:AuthenticationKey>
            <a:UserGrpId>YYY</a:UserGrpId>
            <a:UserId>XXX</a:UserId>
         </AuthenticateResult>
      </AuthenticateResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>"""))
for _, element in tree:
    element.tag = element.tag.split('}')[-1]

print(tree.root.find('Body').find('AuthenticateResponse').find('AuthenticateResult').find('AuthenticationKey').text)
>>> 'SUPERSECRETTOKEN'
```