# Structure of XML file is preventing me from reading it with python

Tags: xml, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm setting up a python script that will ask for a list of input xml files that all have the same format and read out a specific line from each xml file.

Everything works as I want it to, however I am getting an error when reading from the xml file due to the content of the xml file itself.

I have got the script to work by editing the xml file but this is not a solution for me as I need this script to run thousands of files

here is the code I'm using:

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

file_path = filedialog.askopenfilenames()

tup=0

count = len(file_path)

for i in range(len(file_path)):
    filename = os.path.basename(file_path[tup])
    print('file =',os.path.basename(' '.join(file_path)))
    tree = ET.parse(file_path[tup])
    root = tree.getroot()
    for child in root:
        data = child.tag
        print(data)
    for data in root.findall(data):
        name = data.find('subdata2').text
        print('ID =', name)
    tup +=1
```

and here is an example of the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Data xmlns="link">
    <subdata1 id = "something">
        <subdata2>data
            <subdata3>data</subdata3>
        </subdata2>
    </subdata1>
</Data>
```

The problem comes from the text attached to the root "link3"
it changes the tag of subdata1 from

```
subdata1
```

to

```
 {link}subdata1
```

and this is then changing the output from:

```
ID = data
```

to:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "debug.py", line 25, in <module>
    name = data.find('subdata2').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

is there another way of extracting the data from this xml file that doesn't involve modifying the xml file itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can strip the namespaces from the parsed xml instead of the xml itself.

```
tree = ET.iterparse(file_path)
for _, el in tree:
    if '}' in el.tag:
        el.tag = el.tag.split('}', 1)[1]  # strip all namespaces
root = tree.root
for child in root:
    # ... (REST OF CODE)
```

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412496/python-elementtree-module-how-to-ignore-the-namespace-of-xml-files-to-locate-ma)

---

Also, another option if you don't mind a lack of speed but want ultimate simplicity, you can use untangle. Being as how your XML is apparently all structured the same, this might be convenient for you.

```
import untangle

root = untangle.parse(file_path)
print(root.Data.subdata1['id'])
print(root.Data.subdata1.subdata2.cdata)
```

---

I also forgot my favorite option. xmltodict converts xml into Python OrderedDict objects.

```
import xmltodict

with open(xmlPath, 'rb') as fd:
    xmlDict = xmltodict.parse(fd)
print(xmlDict['Data']['subdata1']['@id'])
print(xmlDict['Data']['subdata1']['subdata2']['#text'])
```

As you can see, namespaces won't be an issue. And if you are familiar with Python dicts then it will be very simple to iterate through and find what you want.