# Reading and printing values from tcx files in Python

Tags: python, xml, dom

I am writing Python code to read a TCX file that downloads from my Polar Heart Rate monitor. I have tried using the xml.dom library and what I am getting appears to be some sort of class or memory location.

The data I am looking at has heart rates (and other information) for each second in an exercise file.

Here is a part of the data file:

```
<Trackpoint>
    <Time>2019-05-24T12:12:10.000Z</Time>
    <Position><LatitudeDegrees>37.09307833</LatitudeDegrees
    <LongitudeDegrees>-84.60697</LongitudeDegrees></Position>
    <DistanceMeters>0.10000000149011612</DistanceMeters>
    <HeartRateBpm><Value>73</Value></HeartRateBpm>
    <Cadence>0</Cadence><SensorState>Present</SensorState>
</Trackpoint>
<Trackpoint>
    <Time>2019-05-24T12:12:11.000Z</Time>
    <Position><LatitudeDegrees>37.09307667</LatitudeDegrees>
    <LongitudeDegrees>-84.60697667</LongitudeDegrees></Position>
    <HeartRateBpm><Value>73</Value></HeartRateBpm>
    <Cadence>0</Cadence><SensorState>Present</SensorState>
</Trackpoint>
<Trackpoint>
    <Time>2019-05-24T12:12:12.000Z</Time>
    <Position><LatitudeDegrees>37.09307167</LatitudeDegrees>
    <LongitudeDegrees>-84.60698167</LongitudeDegrees></Position>
    <DistanceMeters>0.800000011920929</DistanceMeters>
    <HeartRateBpm><Value>73</Value></HeartRateBpm>
    <Cadence>0</Cadence><SensorState>Present</SensorState>
</Trackpoint>
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
from xml.dom import minidom
from datetime import *

xmldoc = minidom.parse("testfile.tcx")
print(xmldoc)


tcd = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName("TrainingCenterDatabase")[0]

activitiesElement = tcd.getElementsByTagName("Activities")[0]

activities = activitiesElement.getElementsByTagName("Activity")

for activity in activities:
    sport = activity.attributes["Sport"]
    sportName = sport.value

    idElement = activity.getElementsByTagName("Id")[0]
    timeOfDay = idElement.firstChild.data
    year = int(timeOfDay[0:4])
    month = int(timeOfDay[5:7])
    day = int(timeOfDay[8:10])
    date = datetime(year,month,day)
    #print(sportName, month, day, year)
    print(sportName, date)


trackPoints = tcd.getElementsByTagName("Time")
heartRate = tcd.getElementsByTagName("Value")


print(type(trackPoints))
print(type(heartRate))

i=0

while i <= 10:
    print(trackPoints[i], heartRate[i])
    i += 1
```

This is the output I am getting from this program:

```
C:\Python\Heart Rate Data>python "c:/Python/Heart Rate 
Data/readfiletest4.py"
<xml.dom.minidom.Document object at 0x00000217F5A86948>
Running 2019-05-24 00:00:00
<class 'xml.dom.minicompat.NodeList'>
<class 'xml.dom.minicompat.NodeList'>
<DOM Element: Time at 0x217f5a92048> <DOM Element: Value at 0x217f5a4daf8>
<DOM Element: Time at 0x217f5a92638> <DOM Element: Value at 0x217f5a4dc28>
<DOM Element: Time at 0x217f5a92b90> <DOM Element: Value at 0x217f5a923d8>
<DOM Element: Time at 0x217f5aae210> <DOM Element: Value at 0x217f5a92930>
<DOM Element: Time at 0x217f5aae768> <DOM Element: Value at 0x217f5a92f20>
<DOM Element: Time at 0x217f5aaed58> <DOM Element: Value at 0x217f5aae508>
<DOM Element: Time at 0x217f5aaf3d8> <DOM Element: Value at 0x217f5aaeaf8>
<DOM Element: Time at 0x217f5aaf9c8> <DOM Element: Value at 0x217f5aaf178>
<DOM Element: Time at 0x217f5ab0048> <DOM Element: Value at 0x217f5aaf768>
<DOM Element: Time at 0x217f5ab0638> <DOM Element: Value at 0x217f5aafd58>
<DOM Element: Time at 0x217f5ab0c28> <DOM Element: Value at 0x217f5ab03d8>
```

I am hoping to get some sort of array that has various elements from the TCX file so that I can ultimately do some graphing, etc.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the text of the XML element you need to use the 'text' property of the element.

(You can have a look at this code https://github.com/vkurup/python-tcxparser)

```
while i <= 10:
    print(trackPoints[i].text, heartRate[i].text)
    i += 1
```

A complete working example (based on sample XML) below:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import re

with open('1.tcx') as xml_file:
    xml_str = xml_file.read()
    xml_str = re.sub(' xmlns="[^"]+"', '', xml_str.decode('utf-8'), count=1)
    root = ET.fromstring(xml_str)
    activities = root.findall('.//Activity')
    for activity in activities:
        print('-- {} --'.format(activity.attrib['Sport']))
        tracking_points = activity.findall('.//Trackpoint')
        for tracking_point in list(tracking_points):
            children = list(tracking_point)
            print('Time: {}, HR Value: {}'.format(children[0].text,
                                                  list(children[4])[0].text))
```

1.tcx

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<TrainingCenterDatabase xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabase/v2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation
="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtensionv2.xsd http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDat
abase/v2 http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/TrainingCenterDatabasev2.xsd">

  <Activities>
    <Activity Sport="Biking">
      <Id>2010-06-26T10:06:11Z</Id>
      <Lap StartTime="2010-06-26T10:06:11Z">
        <TotalTimeSeconds>906.1800000</TotalTimeSeconds>
        <DistanceMeters>9762.4433594</DistanceMeters>
        <MaximumSpeed>15.2404995</MaximumSpeed>
        <Calories>493</Calories>
        <AverageHeartRateBpm xsi:type="HeartRateInBeatsPerMinute_t">
          <Value>179</Value>
        </AverageHeartRateBpm>
        <MaximumHeartRateBpm xsi:type="HeartRateInBeatsPerMinute_t">
          <Value>194</Value>
        </MaximumHeartRateBpm>
        <Intensity>Active</Intensity>
        <Cadence>84</Cadence>
        <TriggerMethod>Location</TriggerMethod>
        <Track>
          <Trackpoint>
            <Time>2010-06-26T10:06:11Z</Time>
            <Position>
              <LatitudeDegrees>40.7780135</LatitudeDegrees>
              <LongitudeDegrees>-73.9665795</LongitudeDegrees>
            </Position>
            <AltitudeMeters>36.1867676</AltitudeMeters>
            <DistanceMeters>0.0629519</DistanceMeters>
            <HeartRateBpm xsi:type="HeartRateInBeatsPerMinute_t">
              <Value>148</Value>
            </HeartRateBpm>
            <SensorState>Absent</SensorState>
          </Trackpoint>
          <Trackpoint>
            <Time>2010-06-26T10:06:12Z</Time>
            <Position>
              <LatitudeDegrees>40.7780136</LatitudeDegrees>
              <LongitudeDegrees>-73.9665778</LongitudeDegrees>
            </Position>
            <AltitudeMeters>35.2254639</AltitudeMeters>
            <DistanceMeters>0.1698548</DistanceMeters>
            <HeartRateBpm xsi:type="HeartRateInBeatsPerMinute_t">
              <Value>148</Value>
            </HeartRateBpm>
            <SensorState>Absent</SensorState>
          </Trackpoint>
          <Trackpoint>
            <Time>2010-06-26T10:06:17Z</Time>
            <Position>
              <LatitudeDegrees>40.7780147</LatitudeDegrees>
              <LongitudeDegrees>-73.9665789</LongitudeDegrees>
            </Position>
            <AltitudeMeters>34.2641602</AltitudeMeters>
            <DistanceMeters>0.5907414</DistanceMeters>
            <HeartRateBpm xsi:type="HeartRateInBeatsPerMinute_t">
              <Value>152</Value>
            </HeartRateBpm>
            <SensorState>Absent</SensorState>
          </Trackpoint>
          <Trackpoint>
            <Time>2010-06-26T10:06:24Z</Time>
            <Position>
              <LatitudeDegrees>40.7780246</LatitudeDegrees>
              <LongitudeDegrees>-73.9665919</LongitudeDegrees>
            </Position>
            <AltitudeMeters>34.7448730</AltitudeMeters>
            <DistanceMeters>1.9415363</DistanceMeters>
            <HeartRateBpm xsi:type="HeartRateInBeatsPerMinute_t">
              <Value>147</Value>
            </HeartRateBpm>
            <SensorState>Absent</SensorState>
          </Trackpoint>
          <Trackpoint>
            <Time>2010-06-26T10:06:25Z</Time>
            <Position>
              <LatitudeDegrees>40.7780338</LatitudeDegrees>
              <LongitudeDegrees>-73.9665851</LongitudeDegrees>
            </Position>
            <AltitudeMeters>34.7448730</AltitudeMeters>
            <DistanceMeters>1.9993043</DistanceMeters>
            <HeartRateBpm xsi:type="HeartRateInBeatsPerMinute_t">
              <Value>147</Value>
            </HeartRateBpm>
            <SensorState>Present</SensorState>
          </Trackpoint>
          <Trackpoint>
            <Time>2010-06-26T10:06:28Z</Time>
            <Position>
              <LatitudeDegrees>40.7780800</LatitudeDegrees>
              <LongitudeDegrees>-73.9665492</LongitudeDegrees>
            </Position>
            <AltitudeMeters>34.2641602</AltitudeMeters>
            <DistanceMeters>7.9581327</DistanceMeters>
            <HeartRateBpm xsi:type="HeartRateInBeatsPerMinute_t">
              <Value>148</Value>
            </HeartRateBpm>
            <Cadence>1</Cadence>
            <SensorState>Present</SensorState>
            <Extensions>
              <TPX xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2" CadenceSensor="Bike"/>
            </Extensions>
          </Trackpoint>
          <Trackpoint>
            <Time>2010-06-26T10:06:30Z</Time>
            <Position>
              <LatitudeDegrees>40.7781448</LatitudeDegrees>
              <LongitudeDegrees>-73.9665005</LongitudeDegrees>
            </Position>
            <AltitudeMeters>32.8222656</AltitudeMeters>
            <DistanceMeters>15.3775177</DistanceMeters>
            <HeartRateBpm xsi:type="HeartRateInBeatsPerMinute_t">
              <Value>151</Value>
            </HeartRateBpm>
            <Cadence>42</Cadence>
            <SensorState>Present</SensorState>
            <Extensions>
              <TPX xmlns="http://www.garmin.com/xmlschemas/ActivityExtension/v2" CadenceSensor="Bike"/>
            </Extensions>
          </Trackpoint>
        </Track>
      </Lap>
    </Activity>
  </Activities>

</TrainingCenterDatabase>
```

output

```
-- Biking --
Time: 2010-06-26T10:06:11Z, HR Value: 148
Time: 2010-06-26T10:06:12Z, HR Value: 148
Time: 2010-06-26T10:06:17Z, HR Value: 152
Time: 2010-06-26T10:06:24Z, HR Value: 147
Time: 2010-06-26T10:06:25Z, HR Value: 147
Time: 2010-06-26T10:06:28Z, HR Value: 148
Time: 2010-06-26T10:06:30Z, HR Value: 151
```

Comment: Sorry for the inexperience...Talk to me about the "import requests" command.  I installed the requests library using pipenv and my terminal says it was installed correctly.  However, I am still getting an error that points to line 7: "r = requests.get(SAMPLE_TCX)"  I am also getting a "unresolved import 'requests'" message.  What am I missing?

Comment: Lets try and bypass the requests issue by creating a local file on your hard drive. So go to the URL that is pointed by SAMPLE_TCX, copy the data and save it to local file (lets call it 1.tcx). Assuming that your python script and the XML. The code should be modified accordingly. I will update the answer.

Comment: I ran your code against a renamed file (my data) 1.tcx.  I am getting an error on line 6 of your code... "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'"

Comment: I guess where I am confused is that in line 5, you use the .read() method and assign that to xml_str.  the read() method should return a string.  Then in line 6, you use a formula that (I think) checks the value and uses a .decode('utp-8') method to correct the value if needed.  I am getting a error that says the .decode() method will not work on a string variable...  What am I missing?

Comment: What is the python version that you are using?

Comment: The explanation for line 5 can be found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13412496/python-elementtree-module-how-to-ignore-the-namespace-of-xml-files-to-locate-ma