# Remove all namespaces from xml

Tags: python, regex, xml

Is there a way to remove namespaces from an xml (where I know there aren't any name collisions)? Currently I'm doing this for each known namespace:

```
s = re.sub(r'(<\/?)md:', r'\1', s)             # remove md:
s = re.sub(r'\s+xsi:', ' ', s)                 # remove xsi:
```

But I was wondering if there was something more generic that could be used. There are no CDATA allowed in the particular xml.

Comment: *Don't*. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/836748

Comment: You never actually need that, when you use an xml parser you can always specify all the required namespaces.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes the issue is there are a lot of namespaces, not all of which I know (for example, there can be future namespace added in), so this is a bit more general-purpose for now. It's worked so far on production processing ~1M documents a day.

Comment: You can use XSLT processing to achieve this reliably. Just combine the _identity template_ with a template that transforms `name()`s to `local-name()`s. Then call the XSLT from Python.

Comment: @zx485 that's an interesting approach, thanks for the feedback. Would you be able to add an answer that shows how you'd do that?

Comment: Here's an old answer which shows how to remove all namespaces from tags and attributes https://stackoverflow.com/a/33997423/2318649

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the XSLT approach by calling the following XSLT-1.0 template from Python. It combines the *identity template* with a template that transforms the (full) `name()`s of the elements to their `local-name()`s only. That means all `<ns1:abc>` elements are transformed to `<abc>`, for example. The namespaces are omitted.

However, how useful this is depends on your usecase. It reduces the amount of information, so handle with care.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">   <!-- Identity template copies all nodes (except for elements, which are handled by the other template) -->
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*">           <!-- Removes all namespaces from all elements -->
        <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Apply it with an XSLT-1.0 (or above) framework/processor.